# Is it possible to generate duplicate UUIDs in the same millisecond?

Tags: uuid

Is it possible to create two duplicate UUIDs one after the other? I'm unfamiliar with how UUIDs are generated, but I would guess that if you created two separate UUIDs from the same MAC address in the same millisecond, then they would be exactly the same. Is this true?

I guess I'm asking two questions in one. I'm very interested to know what parameters are used to generate a random UUID. I'm guessing its more than just timestamp and MAC address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Python UUID package, it takes the timestamp and generates a random number `random.randrange(1<<14L)` for `UUIDv1`, so you are taking a nanosecond timestamp plus a random number from `1` to `16384`, so... My guess is it would be *possible* but highly unlikely.

If you are worried about this being an issue, you always have `UUIDv3`, `UUIDv4`, and my choice, `UUIDv5`.

Comment: Surely you cannot generate a random number, only pseudo-random? If a random number is generated by a another random number, what is generates *that* random number?

Comment: My answer meant it takes the nanosecond time stamp and also generates a random number. The only way for duplication for two UUIDs having the same id, if they are created at the exact same time means that you would have to get the same random number twice within that nanosecond.

Comment: Oh ok, was not aware it used nanoseconds instead of milliseconds. Thanks - but that still leaves me wondering how the random number (not the UUID) is calculated. When you say `and also generates a random number` - I'm just curious as to how *that* is generated.

Comment: In the Python UUID package, `uuid.uuid1` -> `UUIDv1` takes `node` and `clock_seq` as parameters. If `clock_seq` is not given, it generates a random number `clock_seq = random.randrange(1<<14L)` which is `1..16384` it then produces `clock_seq_low = clock_seq & 0xffL` and `clock_seq_hi_variant = (clock_seq >> 8L) & 0x3fL` to be passed to the UUID generator. `If 'clock_seq' is given, it is used as the sequence number; otherwise a random 14-bit sequence number is chosen.`

Comment: Note that while using `uuid.uuid1` you usually just call `uuid.uuid()` as `node` and `clock_seq` are optional.